# Change Admin Bar "Visit Site" URL

Tags: functions, admin

I am using this code to open the admin "Visit Site" URL in a new window. How could I modify the code to also point the URL to a custom page? e.g. www.domain.com/blog

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'customize_my_wp_admin_bar', 80 );
function customize_my_wp_admin_bar( $wp_admin_bar ) {

    //Get a reference to the view-site node to modify.
    $node = $wp_admin_bar->get_node('view-site');

    //Change target
    $node->meta['target'] = '_blank';

    //Update Node.
    $wp_admin_bar->add_node($node);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The admin bar is using the home_url() function which you can modify the result by using the "home_url" filter, this will change a lot of links on your admin area so looks like it's not the best solution, anyway remember to use the is_admin() conditional tag or you will affect everything on the front end too.

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/admin-bar.php#L357

The second option is to set the href directly:

```
    $node->href = 'https://www.google.com';
```